# How to Draw a line pixel by pixel using objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, core-animation

I want to draw a line(on iphone) such that i can view each pixel being draw.

I am currently calling the drawRect method using a timer.

Following is the code where i am drawing a wave using the values from an array:

```
static int i=0;
int x = 10;
int y = 0;
int x2;
int y2;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
// Drawing code.
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);
CGContextBeginPath(c);
NSLog(@"fired...");
int ecg[358] = {36, 37, 37, 36, 34, 33, 33, .... ,36}; //Assume the data is there

CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x, y);

x2 = i;
y2 = ecg[i];
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x2, y2);
x = x2;
y = y2;

CGContextStrokePath(c); 
[self setNeedsDisplay];
i++;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(drawRect:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I can only see one line at a time being draw when drawRect is called. But i dont see the entire image. I cannot think of a different approach in order to see the wave being draw on the screen.

Also the method initWithFrame is never called so had to go with awakeFromNib to declare the timer, correct me if i am wrong.

Any pointers to animate the drawing of a line would help.

Thank you

Comment: Every time drawRect is called the context is cleared. So you have to re-draw everything up to the point you want.

Comment: @DarkDust: Yes i understand that, can you suggest a different approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-draw the stuff up to the point that you want, like:

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        x2 = j;
        y2 = ecg[j];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x2, y2);
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(c);
```

Do not call `setNeedsDisplay:` in your `drawRect:`, it causes the view to be redrawn immediately afterwards over and over again. Also, try to avoid global variables. For examples, there's no need to "cache" x, x2, y and y2 here. Define them inside `drawRect:`.

Comment: @DarkDust: By doing this it will just draw my first line. Calling CGContextStrokePath(c) outside the loop will draw the wave all at once. I want to see the wave being draw. So i think setNeedsDisplay is required but not sure where.

Comment: @Nisarg: You're right, the stroking needs to be done outside the loop. As for the "I want to see it being drawn": just set up a timer that fires regularly, and in the timer callback your call `[myView setNeedsDisplay]`. In fact, this is where `i` should be incremented (and please give it a more descriptive name ;-)

Comment: @DarkDust: My timer is calling drawRect. I am new to objective C and not aware of how to call [self setNeedsDisplay] from the timer.

Comment: @Nisarg: You're not supposed to call `drawRect:` yourself, you probably won't have the correct graphics context set up. You're supposed to call `setNeedsDisplay` instead which says to the graphics system: *Redraw me as soon as possible* (which is not "now", BTW, but probably in the next runloop iteration). Read up on how to use timers (it's simple, plenty of examples available), and in the callback you just do `[self setNeedsDisplay];` and you're done.

Comment: @DarkDust: I tried that, this is the code now:

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
 NSTimer *timer;
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(ReDraw) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) ReDraw
{
 i++;
 [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
I have an 'if' statement in the drawRect which executes the loop part only if (i<358)
I am still getting the same result.

BTW thanks for the help till now.

Comment: And inside your `drawRect:`, do you draw all the lines from 0 up to `i` ? Because that is what you need to do.

Comment: Oh yes... i did that, now i have a wave drawn slowly but there is always a line from the starting point (x=0, y=30) to (x2,y2) while the wave is being drawn... i wonder why... heres the code: 
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x, y);
 if(i<358)
 {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) 
  {
   
   x2 = j;
   y2 = ecg[j];
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x2, y2);
   x = x2;
   y = y2;
  }
 }
 CGContextStrokePath(c);

Comment: @Nisarg: That's most likely because the path is implicitly closed (see [CGContextClosePath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClosePath)). You can try to move to the first point before calling `CGContextStrokePath`.

Comment: @DarkDust: Thanks... making the variables local did the trick...
Though i think this is an inefficient way as i am drawing the lines upto 'i' every time...

Comment: BTW my app has 2 views and this drawing is on the 2nd... the drawing doesnt start again when i go back and come to this view again. any thoughts?

Comment: @Nisarg: You might want to speed up the drawing (make it more efficient) by creating a CGPath as instance variable (do not use globals if you can avoid it) and just add another point to that path each time and then stroke it. Then there's also UIBezierPath.