# How do I draw a line so that it appears onscreen, pixel by pixel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm new to Objective-C, and I'm trying to draw a line onscreen in such a way that it appears one pixel at a time.

Using the following drawing code, I'm able to draw the line, but it all appears onscreen at once, rather than incrementally over time:

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat colour[4] = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, colour);
CGContextBeginPath(c);
NSLog(@"fired...");
int line[10] = {136, 137, 138, 139,140,145,180,155}; 

CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x,0);

for (i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    x = line[i];
   // y = line[j];

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x,0);
    x = x;
    //y = y;
}

CGContextStrokePath(c); 
x=x;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
//i++;
```

How can I achieve this pixel-by-pixel appearance of a line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Draw a line pixel by pixel using objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514410/how-to-draw-a-line-pixel-by-pixel-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a delay and a window refresh to your for-loop if you want to see it being drawn.

Comment: how to add that... can u please help me out with the solution.. from many hours i have struck with this..

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to program objective-c or iOS so I cannot write the exact code. Try googling it or search stackoverflow directly for how to do a sleep and a refresh or redraw.

Comment: hi dontomaso how to add the delay and window refresh... can u help me out with the solution...

Comment: @sasha: try extending your line a pixel in a separate function and call that function every 0.25(or n) seconds...the display will update automatically coz of your setNeedsDisplay

Comment: @xs2bush: Can u try to send a basic code how to do that... because i am very new to coding in objective c... so can u help me with the issue.. it will be very helpfull to me... thanks in advance..

Comment: you're new great but you need to learn by doing things not asking others to code for you...you have all the code in your question..its just the matter of calling it...Ill add an answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Extend your line pixel by pixel in a function and call it after 0.5 secs(say). Your array having line points must be global and u would also need a global counter:

int line[10] = {136, 137, 138, 139,140,145,180,155};
int i=0;

```
- (void)extendLine {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat colour[4] = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, colour);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    NSLog(@"fired...");

    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x,0);

    x = line[i];
    // y = line[j];

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x,0);
    x = x;
    //y = y;

    CGContextStrokePath(c); 
    x=x;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    i++;
}
```

Call:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(extendLine) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Im not very experienced with graphics contexts and stuff so I dont know if you need to call

```
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, colour);
CGContextBeginPath(c);
```

every time or just once.