# Draw animated line for speed changes using CoreGraphics and CGContextAddLine

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I created an iPhone app which shows your current speed using CLLocation (CoreLocation framework).

```
 - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location     
   {
   speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [location speed]];
   }
```

This is my code to show the current speed in a label. I want to add a small animated line with the ups and downs of your speed (which works automatically).

The result should be something like this: http://cl.ly/image/0j2U0D462600

I think this should be possible with CGContextAddLine (CoreGraphics)?

I saw this question but it still isn't clear for me:  [How to Draw a line pixel by pixel using objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514410/how-to-draw-a-line-pixel-by-pixel-using-objective-c)

Thanks!

Comment: that page is not found

Comment: @A'saDickens It should be working right now.

Comment: i will give you some code i used to make a signature pallete, it uses a blank image view though but i think you could adapt it to your project

Answer (score 0):

this code takes the graphics context and draws a line in it that is black, to the different locations depending on a saved point from the last point it's at.

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        mImgViewSig.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

last point is the last point that was drawn to, the current point is the point the user touched